# gclient sync failed when downloading chromium

Tags: python, webrtc

I'm doing gclient sync in linux and windows and in both I'm getting the same error after around 15 min.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jgd/dev/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 2295, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/home/jgd/dev/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 2281, in main
    return dispatcher.execute(OptionParser(), argv)
  File "/home/jgd/dev/depot_tools/subcommand.py", line 252, in execute
    return command(parser, args[1:])
  File "/home/jgd/dev/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 2030, in CMDsync
    ret = client.RunOnDeps('update', args)
  File "/home/jgd/dev/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 1340, in RunOnDeps
    work_queue.flush(revision_overrides, command, args, options=self._options)
  File "/home/jgd/dev/depot_tools/gclient_utils.py", line 1047, in run
    self.item.run(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/jgd/dev/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 766, in run
    self.ParseDepsFile()
  File "/home/jgd/dev/depot_tools/gclient.py", line 562, in ParseDepsFile
    gclient_eval.Check(deps_content, filepath, global_scope, local_scope)
  File "/home/jgd/dev/depot_tools/gclient_eval.py", line 240, in Check
    result_scope = _gclient_exec(content, global_scope, filename=path)
  File "/home/jgd/dev/depot_tools/gclient_eval.py", line 185, in _gclient_exec
    _visit_in_module(stmt)
  File "/home/jgd/dev/depot_tools/gclient_eval.py", line 169, in _visit_in_module
    value = _gclient_eval(node.value, global_scope, filename=filename)
  File "/home/jgd/dev/depot_tools/gclient_eval.py", line 146, in _gclient_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/home/jgd/dev/depot_tools/gclient_eval.py", line 145, in _convert
    getattr(node, 'lineno', '<unknown>')))
ValueError: unexpected AST node: <_ast.Num object at 0x1cf5d10> Num(n=1) (file '/home/jgd/dev/jgd/webrtc/src/chromium/src/buildtools/DEPS', line 1)
Error: Command '/usr/bin/python -u src/sync_chromium.py --target-revision 316b880c55452eb694a27ba4d1aa9e74ec9ef342' returned non-zero exit status 1 in /home/jgd/dev/jgd/webrtc
```

Both are fresh installed and I have no idea about what is happening, it is the first time that this occurs to me. Know anyone how to solve it?

EDIT: The DEPS file that appears in error trace is the following:

```
recursion = 1
use_relative_paths = True

vars = {
  "git_url": "https://chromium.googlesource.com",

  "clang_format_rev": "0ed791d1387a3c9146ea6c453c646f3c0fc97784",   # r282136
  "libcxx_revision": "b1ece9c037d879843b0b0f5a2802e1e9d443b75a",    # r256621
  "libcxxabi_revision": "0edb61e2e581758fc4cd4cd09fc588b3fc91a653", # r256323
}

deps = {
  "clang_format/script":
      Var("git_url") + "/chromium/llvm-project/cfe/tools/clang-format.git@" +
      Var("clang_format_rev"),
  "third_party/libc++/trunk":
      Var("git_url") + "/chromium/llvm-project/libcxx.git" + "@" +
      Var("libcxx_revision"),
  "third_party/libc++abi/trunk":
      Var("git_url") + "/chromium/llvm-project/libcxxabi.git" + "@" +
      Var("libcxxabi_revision"),
}
```

AFAIK this is auto-generated.

Comment: I cloned it couple of hours back on my Ubuntu-16.04, its fine for me. What are the commands you executed ?

Comment: git clone and gclient sync

Comment: Delete the directory and start freshly in new directory it should work.

Comment: @Ajay I have tried it several, several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the version of Python used. As you can see in command error prompt, the version that I have used is not 2.7+ as recomended in chromium website. Doing the change from Python to Python2.7 solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

sync_chromium.py was removed back in December, replaced by a more efficient and far smaller download package. I suggest you follow the instructions at https://webrtc.org/native-code/development and get a newer checkout. It should be less likely to have download problems.

Comment: I need to do sync_chromium.py becuase I'm in the revision without this smaller download package.

Comment: I don't follow. If you're using the latest HEAD you won't have that file: https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/

Comment: I'm not using the latest HEAD

Comment: I'm afraid you might have to. Support for old branches is limited in time (with no SLA) and depot tools auto-updates for each run. What you could try is to run `git reset` on your depot tools repo to change it back to around the date when your branch is from. Then maybe it'll work.

Comment: That said, the problem is probably due to not having Python 2.7 as the answer above suggested, if that's the case.